# Alternative to the pandas negation operator

Tags: python, pandas, jinja2

I'm trying to use the pandas negation operator `~` in one of my `jinja2` templates but I believe its conflicting with their [special operator](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#other-operators) `~`.

```
{% for row in df.loc[ ~(df['is_test_result_pass']) , : ].itertuples() %}
```

yields the following exception...

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError, unexpected '~'
```

I could do the operation on the python side and pass another variable with the negated selection but what's the method name equivalent that the ~ operator maps to that I could invoke in the template.

Comment: try `df['is_test_result_pass'].__neg__()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like even more than the `~` operator choked, I couldn't use the column slice operator either `:`, it would yield a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` when the template compiled

However both the following worked identically using the tip from @piRSquared....

```
{% for row in df.loc[ df['is_test_result_pass'].eq(False) ].itertuples() %}
{% for row in df.loc[ df['is_test_result_pass'].__neg__() ].itertuples() %}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`numpy.logical_not`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_not.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'is_test_result_pass':[True, False, False, True]})

print (df['is_test_result_pass'])
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
Name: is_test_result_pass, dtype: bool

print (np.logical_not(df['is_test_result_pass']))
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
Name: is_test_result_pass, dtype: bool
```